# Ada left hand of assignment must not be limited type

Tags: task, procedure, ada

I am at loss after spending hours on this.

Protected type declaration:

```
   protected type AdditionMachine is
      procedure setTask (Item : in WorkerTask);
      procedure getTask (Item : out WorkerTask);
      procedure calculate;
   private
      machineType : String (1 .. 1) := "A";
      job : workerTask;
   end AdditionMachine;
```

Task:

```
   task body SimpleTask1 is 
     Available     : Natural := ADDITION_MACHINES;
      Elements      : array (1 .. ADDITION_MACHINES) of AdditionMachine;
   begin
     loop
        select
           when Available > 0 =>
              accept getMachine (machine : out AdditionMachine) do
                  machine := Elements(Available);
                  Available := Available - 1;
              end getMachine;
        or
            accept addMachine (machine : in AdditionMachine) do
                 Available := Available + 1;
                 Elements(Available) := machine;
              end addMachine;
        end select;
     end loop;
   end  SimpleTask1;
```

At line `Elements(Available) := machine;` and `machine := Elements(Available);` I get "left hand of assingment must not be limited type"

I have no idea how to fix this, I've found nothing when I googled, can anyone help?

edit: I now know that protected types are limited, but how do I accomplish a pool of protected objects without something like above?

Comment: `MultiplicationMachine` or `AdditionMachine`?

Comment: Whatever, it's the same. Edited my post.

Answer (score 5):

From [ARM 7.5](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-7-5.html), Limited Types,

> A limited type is (a view of) a type for which copying (such as for an assignment_statement) is not allowed. A nonlimited type is a (view of a) type for which copying is allowed.

However, you *are* allowed to copy accesses to limited objects.

So, if you have declared

```ada
protected type AdditionMachine is
   ...
end AdditionMachine;
type AdditionMachine_Access is access AdditionMachine;
```

you can write something like this (I haven’t tested it):

```ada
task body SimpleTask1 is 
   Available : Natural := ADDITION_MACHINES;
   Elements  : array (1 .. ADDITION_MACHINES) of AdditionMachine_Access
     := (others => new AdditionMachine);
begin
```

You’ll need to take care of deallocating the allocated objects when you’ve done with them (if the program needs to run indefinitely, anyway). I don’t think there’ll be a problem with protected objects (but what happens if a task is waiting on a PO that you deallocate?), and recent GNATs are OK with deallocating tasks provided the tasks have open terminate alternatives, [ARM 9.7.1](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-7-1.html), or have already terminated - perhaps by being aborted).

Comment: How can I use such an object then? Before I could do additionMachine.calculate, and now?

Comment: @algorithmsMadness The same syntax should still work (it would become a shorthand for `additionMachine.all.calculate`).