# Synchronous_Fifo of Objects in Ada

Tags: concurrency, package, ada, fifo

I created record in Ada and later created `Synchronous_Fifo` out of these records:

```
type Basic_Record is record
  Argument_1: Integer;
  Operator: Character;
  Argument_2: Integer;
  Product: Integer;
end record;

package Tasks_Fifo is new Synchronous_Fifo(Basic_Record);
use Tasks_Fifo;
Buffer : Fifo;
```

and this is working fine. Later I wanted to do the same `Synchronous_Fifo` out of objects:

```
package Adding_Machine is
  protected type Add_Machine is
     entry Store_Record(Task_Record: Basic_Record);
     entry Push_Button;
     entry Get_Product(Product: out Integer);
  private
     My_Record : Basic_Record;
     My_Product: Integer;
  end Add_Machine;
end Adding_Machine;

use Adding_Machine;

package Object_Fifo is new Synchronous_Fifo(Add_Machine);
use Object_Fifo;
Buffer: Fifo;
```

and as a result I got several errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Occurrence of package
- actual for non-limited "Element_Type" cannot be a limited type
- instantiation abandoned
```

in line, where I am creating `Object_Fifo`.

How should I create this Fifo? Or maybe there is something wrong with package `Adding_Machine`?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30155627/40851) would help?

Comment: You haven't shown us the specification of `package Synchronous_FIFO`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is shown package `Synchronous_Fifo`:

```
generic
     type Element_Type is private;
package Synchronous_Fifo is
  protected type Fifo is
    entry Push(Item : Element_Type);
    entry Pop(Item : out Element_Type);
  private
    Value : Element_Type;
    Is_New : Boolean := False;
  end Fifo;
end Synchronous_Fifo;

package body Synchronous_Fifo is

 ----------
 -- Fifo --
 ----------

 protected body Fifo is

  ---------
  -- Push --
  ---------

  entry Push (Item : Element_Type) when not Is_New is
  begin
     Value := Item;
     Is_New := True;
  end Push;

  ---------
  -- Pop --
  ---------

  entry Pop (Item : out Element_Type) when Is_New is
  begin
     Item := Value;
     Is_New := False;
  end Pop;

 end Fifo;

end Synchronous_Fifo;
```

I created access to Adding_Machine and later created Fifo out of these accesses.

```
type Adding_Machine_Access is access Adding_Machine;

package Adding_Machines_Fifo is new Synchronous_Fifo(adding_Machine_Access);
use Tasks_Fifo;
Adding_Machines_Fifo : Fifo;
```

It should work.